# Discordant results using IPW and overlap weights (propensity score approach) in sub-group analyses

Tags: propensity-scores, treatment-effect, weights, subset

I am investigating the effect of a treatment on the risk of a disease (% disease=18.5% (515/2784)). To do so, I use a propensity score (PS) approach with two different weights methods: IPW (stabilized version) and overlap weights. I get different results and don't know which one I should trust more.

Some important characteristics:

- the two groups (treated [n=580] / not treated [n=2269]) have quite different characteristics, resulting in a poor overlap between the distributions of the PS in these two populations.
- I am interested in sub-group analyses. My hypothesis is that the treatment has an effect only in specific sub-groups. That leads to quite limited sample sizes in some sub-groups (the two smaller are composed of ~250 and 750 individuals), and that's why I have chosen weighting methods rather that matching.

Given that I am running sub-group analyses, I have included the sub-group variables (4 variables) in the PS model with all possible interactions with the 9 covariates, as suggested in recent papers. So the PS is estimated once in the overall population.

Results:

- With IPW, the balance is good (all SMD<0.1) in the overall population. In the sub-groups analyses, few SMD are >0.1 (between 0.15 and 0.25). However, all the corresponding variables are not associated with the outcome. In addition, I adjust in my final model (the one to test the effect of the treatment on the outcome) on the variables used to build the PS to correct for possible residual confounding effects.
- With overlap weighting, all the SMD are equal to 0, but all the results are non-significant.

My questions are:

- to what extent can I trust the results of the analyses using IPW given that some SMD are >0.1 but all correspond to variables not associated with the outcome (and these variables are adjusted for in the final model)?
- do overlap weights known to lead to more conservative results than other type of weights (with higher risk of false negative results)?

I have used to following code:

```
### propensity score
modlogSP <- glm(anti_chol ~ (rs116503776 + rs10922109 + rs10033900 + rs2230199 + age + gender + ethnicity + hypertension + dm5 + bmi + edu_cat + cvd + smk_cat)^2, family=binomial, data=SEED1_2)
SEED1_2$SP <- modlogSP$fitted.values

### ITPW stabilized
SEED1_2$W <- with(SEED1_2, anti_chol + (1 - anti_chol) * SP / (1 - SP))

### overlap weight
SEED1_2$W <- with(SEED1_2, ifelse(anti_chol==1, 1 - SP, SP))

### overall model
modlog <- glm(OUT1 ~ anti_chol + rs116503776 + rs10922109 + rs10033900 + rs2230199 + age + gender + ethnicity + hypertension + dm5 + bmi + smk_cat + edu_cat + cvd, family=binomial, weights=W, data=SEED1_2)

### subgroup analysis 1 (there are 3 other sub-group analyses according to rs10922109, rs10033900 and rs2230199)
modlog <- glm(OUT1 ~ anti_chol + rs10922109 + rs10033900 + rs2230199 + age + gender + ethnicity + hypertension + dm5 + bmi + smk_cat + edu_cat + cvd, family=binomial,
               weights=W, data=SEED1_2, subset=SEED1_2$rs116503776=='0')
modlog <- glm(OUT1 ~ anti_chol + rs10922109 + rs10033900 + rs2230199 + age + gender + ethnicity + hypertension + dm5 + bmi + smk_cat + edu_cat + cvd, family=binomial,
          weights=W, data=SEED1_2, subset=SEED1_2$rs116503776=='1')
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you computing p-values? If you are using `summary()` on the `glm` objects, those p-values are invalid.

Comment: Hi @Noah. I use a sandwich variance estimator `coeftest(modlog, vcov = sandwich)`

Comment: I am confused of getting different results with the 2 type of weights for the sub-groups with all the SMD<0.1. I am not sure about which one to use and how to justify it...